# How do you maintain cached attributes in parent and child without recursion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have two models below. An index view of shifts is quite difficult to render as is doing payroll calculations, due to having to do joins. Clocks have a lot of attributes and it is necessary to store them separately to allow shifts to be as dynamic as we need them and include traveling, breaks, and work.

To avoid performance issues, the first and last clock's datetimes (I know this is a bad name for this attribute) are stored in the shift as started_at and finished_at as well as the shift's total duration. The duration until the next clock is stored in each Clock.

**The Problem:** Saving a Clock currently calls back to its Shift to recalculate its attributes and then save them, which autosaves all Clocks again. This is not indefinite because of the attribute_changed checks in the callback, but it does recalculate and save multiple times.

**The Question:** How do I ensure that all models maintain correct cached values without recalculating several times when either the parent or the child is saved?

Shift Model:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clocks, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessible :employee_id, :started_at, :finished_at, :duration, :clocks_attributes
  before_save :calculate_cached_attributes

  def calculate_cached_attributes
    clocks.sort_by!(&:datetime)

    self.started_at = clocks.first.datetime

    # assign finished_at if shift is finished and check that there isn't one finished clock
    if clocks.last.activity == :finished && clocks.first != clocks.last
      self.finished_at = clocks.last.datetime
    else
      self.finished_at = nil
    end

    following_clock = nil
    shift_duration = 0

    clocks.reverse.each do |clock|
      if following_clock
        clock.duration = following_clock.datetime - clock.datetime
      else
        clock.duration = 0
      end

      shift_duration += clock.duration unless clock.activity == :break
      following_clock = clock
    end

    self.duration = shift_duration
  end

  def update_cached_attributes!
    if clocks.any? # check if being called because of clocks dependent destroy callback
      save!
    end
  end

end
```

Clock Model:

```
class Clock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shift
  attr_accessible :shift_id, :datetime, :duration, :activity
  symbolize :activity, in: [:work, :travel, :break, :finished] # symbolize gem

  after_save :update_shift_attributes_after_save!
  after_destroy :update_shift_attributes_after_destroy!

  def update_shift_attributes_after_save!
    if (datetime_changed? || activity_changed?) && shift
      shift.update_cached_attributes!
    end
  end

  def update_shift_attributes_after_destroy!
    if shift
      shift.reload.update_cached_attributes!
    end
  end
end
```

Examples requiring (re)calculation:

```
shift.clocks.last.update_attribute(:datetime, Time.now)

# shift may no longer be complete if activity changed from :finished
shift.clocks.last.update_attribute(:activity, :work)

shift.clocks.last.datetime = Time.now
shift.save!

Shift.create!(employee_id: 1, clocks_attributes: [....] )

shift.clocks.last.destroy
```

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible to highlight the problem. Let me know if there is something missing, or if there is a completely different way to do this better.

Comment: Where is `Shift#calculate_cached_attributes` called?

Comment: I forgot the before_save filter... updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to avoid calling the `Clock#update_shift_attributes_after_save!` callback when all you need is to update the cached attributes. It appears that in this case the only cached attribute on `Clock` which is updated is `duration`, so something as simple as the following might work

```
after_save :update_shift_attributes_after_save!, :if => -> { changed.include?("duration") }
```

---

It might be better to make the `Clock` model responsible for updating its own cached attributes. This is how I'd approach doing that.

```
# Clock
CACHED_ATTRIBUTES = [:duration].freeze

def update_cached_attributes!(attrs = {})
  self.class.where(:id => id).update_all(attrs.slice(*CACHED_ATTRIBUTES))  # update_all will NOT trigger callbacks.
                                                                           # This only works for persisted records. You'd need to add logic if you must handle new records.
end

# In Shift#calculate_cached_attributes
clocks.reverse.each do |clock|
  clock.update_cached_attributes!(:duration => following_clock ? (following_clock.datetime - clock.datetime) : 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The Shift has 3 cached attributes as well (duration, started_at, and finished_at) that need to be updated when a Clock's datetime or activity are changed. If the Shift's callback isn't called from the Clock then the Shift won't be updated when the clock is saved. Also, I think the way you suggested updating the Clocks individually in the calculate_cached_attributes method will lead to further recursion due to the multiple transactions.